# How to change label text color and image in prototype cell programmatically when cell selected in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am facing a strange issue. I have a tableview controller in Storyboard with 5 prototype cells. Each cell has one label and one image. I am trying to change text color of the labels and images when cell selected programmatically like as follow.

```
In cellForRowAtIndexPath method
{
     // Using tags I am getting labels from storyboard.

    label1 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
    label2= (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:102];
    label3 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:103];
    label4 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:104];
    label5 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:105];


    label1.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];
    label2.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];
    label3.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];
    label4.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];
    label5.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];
}
```

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

```
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

label1 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
label2 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:102];
label3 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:103];
label4 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:104];
label5 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:105];
```

Here I want to change selected label text color to white when selected otherwise it should be black. I am able to change text color to white when selected but I am not able to set text color back to black if I select other cell.

Answer (score 2):

In `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` you can change the colour back to black.

Use `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`
To get the cell.

Comment: i did like that only. but i am not able to reset to textcolor black that is problem i am facing.

Comment: Can you edit your post and paste in the code from your `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`method?

Comment: i solve this just to set hilighted label color to white in storyboard with out code. Anyway thank you for your quick Response

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create UITableViewCell subclass and override `setSelected:animated:` and `setHighlighted:animated:`. There you can update colors of your labels and change images easily.
In example like this:

```
 - (void)setSelected:(BOOl)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    _label.textColor = (selected ? _selectedColor : _unselectedColor);

}
```

You can change your cell subclass usign Identity inspector.
[image: Changing class using Identity inspector]

Comment: How to change prototype cells to UITableViewCell in storyboard

Comment: Can you change your cell subclass in Identity inspector? Take a look at image in my answer.

Comment: Can you explain little bit more please.

Comment: Maybe the following link can help you get more familiar with Storyboards and Interface Builder: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_5_Storyboards_to_Build_Dynamic_TableViews_with_Prototype_Table_View_Cells